# YouTube API v3: How to get returned 404 (not found) error from PlaylistItems?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I know I can loop through the playlists to compare if the playlist exists on Youtube but that is making two calls (example below) and since I already know the playlist ID I should just be able to make one call.

Two calls to YouTube to loop through playlists (not the way I want to do it):

```
# Playlist ID from URL
$playlist=$_GET['playlist'];

# Playlists from YoUtube
$playlists=$yt->PlaylistsListFeed();

# Loop through the playlists.
foreach($playlists as $playlist_feed)
{
    if($playlist_feed['id']==$playlist)
    {
        # This is a playlist
        $this->setIsPlaylist(TRUE);

        # Assign the Playlist Items to a variable.
        $video_search=$yt->PlaylistItems($playlist_feed['id']);
        break;
    }
}

# If $video_search is not set then playlist does not exist.
if(!isset($video_search))
{
    return $display='That playlist doesn\'t exist. Please choose another.';
}
```

I have the code working for the single call but I can't figure out how to get the 404 error it returns if the playlist ID does not exist (results from YouTube below).

YouTube method (`PlaylistItems`):

```
/**
 * PlaylistItems
 *
 * Retrieves videos from a playlist.
 *
 * @param   int $playlist_id            The ID of the playlist.
 * @param   string $part                The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of
 *                                          one or more playlistItem resource properties that the API
 *                                          response will include. The part names that you can include
 *                                          in the parameter value are id, snippet, and contentDetails.
 * @access  public
 */
public function PlaylistItems($playlist_id, $part='snippet')
{
    # Set the Database instance to a variable.
    $doc=Document::getInstance();
    try
    {
        # Bring $youtube_service into the scope
        global $youtube_service;

        $playlistsItems_optParams=array('maxResults' => 50, 'playlistId' => $playlist_id);
        $playlistsItems=$youtube_service->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems($part, $playlistsItems_optParams);

        $new_array=$this->rebuildArray($playlistsItems, TRUE);

        # Instantiate a new Utility object.
        $utility=new Utility();
        # Sort the playlist array by date.
        $items=$utility->sortByDate($new_array, 'publishedAt');

        return $items;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        # Print Results (below)
        print_r($e); exit;

        if($e->getCode()==404)
        {
            $doc->setError('That playlist doesn\'t exist. Please choose another.');
        }
    }
} #==== End -- PlaylistItems
```

Single call code:

```
# Playlist ID from URL
$playlist=$_GET['playlist'];

# Assign the Playlist Items to a variable.
$video_search=$yt->PlaylistItems($playlist);
```

Return from `PlaylistItems` method

```
Google_ServiceException Object
(
    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => youtube.playlistItem
                    [reason] => playlistNotFound
                    [message] => Not Found
                    [locationType] => parameter
                    [location] => playlistId
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1&key=AIzaSyDVGJhk7DfKKJAaciX14aqyw_YbPaT4fp4: (404) Not Found
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 404
    [file:protected] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Social/Google/io/Google_REST.php
    [line:protected] => 66
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Social/Google/io/Google_REST.php
                    [line] => 36
                    [function] => decodeHttpResponse
                    [class] => Google_REST
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google_HttpRequest Object
                                (
                                    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Content-Type] => application/http
                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
                                            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
                                            [Content-Length] => 
                                        )

                                    [url:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1&key=AIzaSyDVGJhk7DfKKJAaciX14aqyw_YbPaT4fp4
                                    [requestMethod:protected] => GET
                                    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [postBody:protected] => 
                                    [userAgent:protected] => google-api-php-client/0.6.0
                                    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 404
                                    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                                            [date] => Thu, 18 Jul 2013 05:11:11 GMT
                                            [expires] => Thu, 18 Jul 2013 05:11:11 GMT
                                            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                                            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                                            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                            [server] => GSE
                                            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
                                        )

                                    [responseBody:protected] => {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistNotFound",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "playlistId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}

                                    [accessKey] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Social/Google/service/Google_ServiceResource.php
                    [line] => 186
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Google_REST
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google_HttpRequest Object
                                (
                                    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Content-Type] => application/http
                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
                                            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
                                            [Content-Length] => 
                                        )

                                    [url:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1&key=AIzaSyDVGJhk7DfKKJAaciX14aqyw_YbPaT4fp4
                                    [requestMethod:protected] => GET
                                    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [postBody:protected] => 
                                    [userAgent:protected] => google-api-php-client/0.6.0
                                    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 404
                                    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                                            [date] => Thu, 18 Jul 2013 05:11:11 GMT
                                            [expires] => Thu, 18 Jul 2013 05:11:11 GMT
                                            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                                            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                                            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                            [server] => GSE
                                            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
                                        )

                                    [responseBody:protected] => {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistNotFound",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "playlistId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}

                                    [accessKey] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Social/Google/contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php
                    [line] => 425
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => Google_ServiceResource
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => list
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [part] => snippet
                                            [maxResults] => 50
                                            [playlistId] => PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Media/YouTube.php
                    [line] => 412
                    [function] => listPlaylistItems
                    [class] => Google_PlaylistItemsServiceResource
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => snippet
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [maxResults] => 50
                                    [playlistId] => PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/application/modules/Media/Video.php
                    [line] => 1130
                    [function] => PlaylistItems
                    [class] => YouTube
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PLD2D6E64D9CD49E1
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Volumes/Coding/WebDev/CWIS/cwis.org/public/media/video/index.php
                    [line] => 59
                    [function] => displayVideoFeed
                    [class] => Video
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

As you an see everything is either `protected` or `private` so how am I supposed to know if there was an error or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just listing the videos from YouTube and getting their statuses.
This runs as a cron script, every 10 minutes.

```
# Get new uploaded videos from the database.
$get_new_videos=$db->get_results('SELECT `id`, `file_name`, `api` FROM `'.DBPREFIX.'videos` WHERE `new` IS NULL');

# If there are new videos...
if($get_new_videos>0)
{
    # Loop through the new videos
    foreach($get_new_videos as $new_video)
    {
        # Decode the `api` field.
        $api_decoded=json_decode($new_video->api);
        # Get the YouTube Video ID.
        $video_yt_id=$api_decoded->youtube_id;

        if(isset($new_video->file_name))
        {
            # Set the path to the video on the server.
            $video_path='videos'.DS.$new_video->file_name;
        }

        $to=TO_USER;
        $reply_to=FROM_SERVER;
        $subject="Video status from ".DOMAIN_NAME;
        $body='';

        # Check the video status.
        $check_status=$yt->listVideos('status', array('id' => $video_yt_id));

        # Did YouTube return results?
        if(!empty($check_status['items']))
        {
            # Has the video been processed? Default is TRUE. will be changed to FALSE if the video still has "uploaded" status.
            $processed=TRUE;

            # Loop through the videos from YouTube.
            foreach($check_status['items'] as $status)
            {
                if($status['status']['uploadStatus']=="uploaded")
                {
                    # The video has not been processed yet so do not send an email.
                    $processed=FALSE;
                }
                # Check to see if the YouTube upload was a success.
                elseif($status['status']['uploadStatus']=="processed")
                {
                    # Tell the user the video was uploaded.
                    $body.='Your video has been uploaded to YouTube and can be viewed at http://'.FULL_DOMAIN.'media/videos/?video='.$new_video->id;
                }
                # Check if the uploaded video status is rejected.
                elseif($status['status']['uploadStatus']=="rejected")
                {
                    if(isset($new_video->file_name))
                    {
                        # Get the Upload class.
                        require_once MODULES.'Form'.DS.'Upload.php';
                        # Instantiate an Upload object.
                        $upload=new Upload($video_path);
                        # Delete video file from server.
                        $upload->deleteFile($video_path);
                        # Remove extention from filename.
                        $name_no_ext=substr($new_video->file_name, 0, strrpos($new_video->file_name, '.'));
                        # Delete the thumbnails from the server.
                        $upload->deleteFile(IMAGES_PATH.'videos'.DS.'original'.DS.$name_no_ext.'.jpg');
                        $upload->deleteFile(IMAGES_PATH.'videos'.DS.$name_no_ext.'*.jpg', TRUE);

                        # Delete rejected video from YouTube
                        $delete_response=$yt->deleteVideo($video_yt_id);
                    }

                    # Need to delete the entry from the database as well.
                    $db->query('DELETE FROM `'.DBPREFIX.'videos` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($new_video->id).' LIMIT 1');

                    # Check if the rejection status was a duplicate.
                    if($status['status']['rejectionReason']=="duplicate")
                    {
                        # Tell the user the video was a duplicate.
                        $body.='Your video was rejected because it was a duplicate video';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $body.='Your video was not found on YouTube';
            $processed=TRUE;
        }

        # Update database if the video has been "processed".
        if($processed===TRUE)
        {
            # Get the PHPMailer class.
            require_once MODULES.'Email'.DS.'Email.php';
            # Instantiate a new PHPMailer object.
            $mail=new Email();

            $mail->sendEmail($subject, $to, $body, $reply_to);

            # Set new videos to old.
            $db->query('UPDATE `'.DBPREFIX.'videos` SET `new` = 0 WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($new_video->id).' LIMIT 1');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the zend google api library, it's pretty easy to get a playlist feed, and catch any errors that google will return if it does not exist. The simplest solution is to get a list of all playlists on the account and loop through to see if the playlist id matches the id you have, and then go from there to get the playlist entries. That way there really isn't ever going to be any errors or exceptions.  But, that is making multiple calls, which you were trying to avoid.  In order to make a single call, you'd need to have the playlist feed url and then make one call and catch the exception. These are snippets of a couple of the functions I've used when working with YouTube playlists.

Option 1:

```
$this->api = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$this->api->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);

$feed = $this->api->retrieveAllEntriesForFeed($this->api->getPlaylistListFeed('default'));
$playlistEntry = $this->__getPlaylistEntryFromFeed($feed, $playlistID);
//do what you want with the playlist entry, like get the list of all the videos




function __getPlaylistEntryFromFeed($feed, $entryId) {
    foreach($feed as $entry) {
       if($entry->getPlaylistId()->text == $entryId) {
        return $entry;
       }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
try {
   $playlistVideoFeed = $this->api->getPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistFeedUrl. '?v=2&start-index=1');
   //this returns a list of videos in the playlist that you can loop through. see example function below.
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}


function getPlaylistVideos($playlistFeedUrl, $start=1, $total=0, $videos = array()) {
        $playlistVideoFeed = $this->api->getPlaylistVideoFeed($playlistFeedUrl. '?v=2&start-index='.$start);

        foreach ($playlistVideoFeed as $videoEntry) {
            $videos[] = $this->getDataFromVideoEntry($videoEntry);
        }
        $count = count($playlistVideoFeed);

        if(count($videos) < $total && $count != 0) {
            $videos = $this->getPlaylistvideos($playlistFeedUrl, $start + ($count-1), $total, $videos);
        }
        return $videos;
    }
```

To take those examples and use them with your code, you could try look something like this:

```
# Playlist ID from URL
$playlist=$_GET['playlist'];

# Assign the Playlist Items to a variable.
$video_search;
try {
    $video_search = $yt->PlaylistItems($playlist);
} catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
   //there was an error
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hope that helps.